# Changing Linux terminal key bindings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, kali-linux

In Linux terminal, Is there any way to change `Alt` + `Backspace` or `Ctrl` + `W` shortcut which is used to delete the previous word to `Ctrl` + `Backspace`??

Answer (score 0):

Try `stty werase '^H'` in your .bashrc
Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264791/ctrl-backspace-and-ctrl-delete-in-bash